# Understanding disassembled binary from Objdump - What are the fields from the output

Tags: binaryfiles, disassembly, objdump

I get the following output when I disassembled a simple ARM binary file using the command "arm-linux-gnueabihf-objdump -d a.out"

```
00008480 <_start>:
8480:   f04f 0b00   mov.w   fp, #0
8484:   f04f 0e00   mov.w   lr, #0
8488:   bc02        pop {r1}
848a:   466a        mov r2, sp
```

What do different columns represent here?  For example, 8480  and f04f 0b00 (from the 2nd line of code)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first column is the address of the code in memory. `0x8480` means the memory address of this piece of code is `0x8480`.

The second column is the hex representation of the code. `f04f 0b00` means from memory address `0x8480`(included) to `0x8484`(excluded), there are 4 bytes of code, `f0`, `4f`, `0b`, `00`.

The remaining is the disassembled code. They are disassembled from the code in second column.