# How do I read the Symboltable generated by objdump --disassemble, i.e. what does each column mean?

Tags: c++, bash, unix, terminal

This is an excerpt of what I get but I don't understand it. I recognise the instructions but for example what is in the second column?

```
Disassembly of section .text._ZNSt10_Head_baseILm0EOeLb0EE7_M_headERS1_:
_ZNSt10_Head_baseILm0EOeLb0EE7_M_headERS1_:
       0:   55               pushq   %rbp
       1:   48 89 e5         movq    %rsp, %rbp
       4:   48 89 7d f8      movq    %rdi, -8(%rbp)
       8:   48 8b 45 f8      movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
       c:   48 8b 00         movq    (%rax), %rax
       f:   5d               popq    %rbp
      10:   c3               retq
```

Comment: which column, the `48 89 e5`? Those are the actual bytes of the instruction (in hex)

Comment: ohh okay, so what happens when the last column is empty?

Comment: I don't get which column you're asking about. Note that in your question, the columns aren't lined up properly

Comment: I think I fixed it (sorry, how it was before was how my computer formatted it) and I think I understand now as well. So the first column is the bytes of the instruction in hex, the second column is the instruction and the third column is where what the instruction does is saved?

Comment: The third and fourth columns are the instruction

Comment: Okay and if the fourth column is empty?
for example in the last row

Comment: The third and fourth columns are the instruction. `pushq %rbp` is an instruction, so is `retq`

Comment: I think what you are looking for might be already answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48552426/2731508